# Google Place API get latitude & longitude of places

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

How can I get **latitude & longitude** from **Google Place API of android**? My code looks like below..

```
AutocompleteFilter mAutocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES).build();

PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mAutocompleteFilter);
```

I also facing trouble getting results more than **5 results**. I'm using [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteFragment) link for the references. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: If you're getting OVER-QUERY_LIMIT error for more than 5 results, I solved by putting a delay of 0.7 seconds before each api call to google(specifically stating for google geocode api).

Comment: @Dr..Net: Nope. My problem is a different one.

Answer (score 4):

You should do something like that:

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {

  @Override
  public void onResult(PlaceBuffer p) {
    if (p.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
      final Place mPlace = p.get(0);
      LatLng qLoc = mPlace.getLatLng();
      //you can use lat with qLoc.latitude;
      //and long with qLoc.longitude;
    }
    p.release();
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it's going to cost me 2 requests for a single location search. Is it?

Comment: no, I don' think so. I'm pretty sure it's a single request for each location. By the way, you can find more information here https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details

Comment: `Places.GeoDataApi` Is deprecated now